# UnicodeDecodeError при компилировании запроса БД

Tags: python

Выдается ошибка "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte". Поискал в интернете, попробовал в начале файла прописать

```
import sys;
import codecs;
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach());
```

Не помогло. `lastID` - считывает из файла одно значение последнего идентификатора в БД, так как оно получается в текстовом формате - добавляю `int()`.

```
lastID = f.read();

sql1 = "SELECT realty.id,u.id FROM realty INNER JOIN user u on realty.user_id = u.id WHERE realty.id > %s ORDER BY realty.id"

# Выполнить команду запроса (Execute Query).
cursor.execute(sql1, (int(lastID)))
```

В чем ошибка?

---

p.s Немного покопавшись понял, что ему не нравятся русские символы которые лежат в БД. Хз почему, в подключении прописан `charset='utf8'`

Comment: При чтении файла кодировку укажите

Comment: @Nobody, убрал подстановку ```lastID``` ( заместо него поставил просто число ) - ошибка осталась, ему кажется не нравится мой БД запрос. Посмотрел по таблице ASCII, код  0xd2 соответствует символу "Н"(кириллица), хотя в запросе ее нигде нет...

Comment: В БД вы разве не надо ```JOIN user AS u```? Также мне не особо понятно продолжение с ```on```, но в БД я слаб)

Comment: @Nobody, БД запрос сам по себе - ликвиден, и если его выполнять непосредственно через БД - то он выполняется, но компилятор почему то ругается на некоторые данные, которые он получает из БД, как я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло изменения типа соединения с БД. Поменял utf8 на cp1251, и вроде прокатило...